# Java Автоматическое создание классов из базы данных(Excel)

Tags: java, база-данных, классы, excel

Есть база данных, в данном случае, пока что Excel. 
В ней есть четыре столбца, ФИО, дата, число и еще одно число. 
Нужно по каждой строке в excel автоматически создавать классы, для дальнейших манипуляций с ними. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сие можно реализовать на Java.

Comment: Точно классы, а не объекты? Можете, для пущей ясности, привести пример входной информации и результата?

Comment: Коля, видимо имеет ввиду, что надо считывая БД на каждую строку создавать бин с полями `фио/дата/число/число`

Comment: Да, действительно. Создавать объекты, а не классы...

Comment: Спасибо за ваше участие в моем вопросе :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта того, что хотел спросить автор.

1. Необходимо генерировать класс по таблице во время выполнения. Я бы крайне не советовал так делать. Во-первых, это не такая уж тривиальная задача, во-вторых, так как класс появляются только в рантайме - в коде нельзя проводить с ним никаких манипуляций. Код, в котором используются еще не существующие классы, просто не скомпилируется. Если все таки необходимо инкапсулировать содержимое таблицы - лучше воспользуйтесь структурами данных типа `java.util.Map` и `java.util.List`. В вашем случае вполне можно "завернуть" таблицe в `List<Map<String,Object>>`.
2. Необходимо по таблице сгенерировать исходный код класса, который будет использоваться в дальнейшем. В таком случае, необходима еще одна программа, которая посмотрит на таблицу, на типы и наименования полей и создаст текстовый файл, в котором будет описан исходный код класса, который в дальнейшем можно будет подключить к основному проекту.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ/совет